# Reading string constants is thread safe?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I have an Indy custom TCP Server and when I create the object I pass some string parameters (like name, password...) that are stored in the private section of the class. This is the only time when those fields are writen to (before I start the server). Every write makes a new copy of the string, not pass the reference, to be sure that those strings belongs only to this object. Now, after I start the server and receive some connections, it is safe to read those string fields in those new threads without adding some critical sections ? The values won't change in the time when that server is active...

Comment: "Every write makes a new copy of the string, not pass the reference, to be sure that those strings belongs only to this object." It is not clear to me exactly what you mean here. And are you aware of the fact that strings are reference counted and use COW semantics?

Comment: I use this: `FPass:= Copy(APass, 1, Length(APass));`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Yes, then `FPass` will be guaranteed to point to a long string heap object of refcount 1.

Comment: You only need to pass the first argument when you call Copy. And I'm not sure you even need to do that. Can't you use COW?

Comment: If there is no writing after multiple threads start accessing the data, then reading is thread safe. But your question would be more clear if you have added some code. Merely describing code when you are dealing with thread safety is far from optimal. Devil is in the details.

Comment: I know, but in this case there is only simple read and writes of those string variables... Writing only once, then read from multiple threads...

Comment: Unfortunately, strings aren't very simple because of their reference counting. Even if you only read a string, you might change (write to) the heap object (specifically, to update the ref count).

Comment: @andreas the ref count is managed with atomic increments. I don't think Copy function call is needed for scenario as described.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I can see in System.pas that it is a `LOCK INC` assembly instruction in 32-bit and an `AtomicIncrement` in 64-bit. Sounds safe, then.